# How to disable resizing and close button of a Custom Task Pane?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, ms-office, vsto

How can I prevent an Office Custom Task Pane for resizing, so that it's only and always have the dimensions and can't be closing with the "close" button.

```
myCustomTaskPane.Height = 500;
myCustomTaskPane.Width = 500;
```

Comment: If you are setting the width and the height, I am assuming you are not docking your task pane. Why not simply use a pop-up form, then?

Comment: @Mathias in this project i should use a Custom Task Pane!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where _tp is a reference to your task pane (not the CustomTaskPane container), _ctp is the CustomTaskPane container, iw is the InspectorWrapperDictionary:

```
 void _tpvals_VisibleChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            _tp.tmr.Start();
        }
```

And, in your task pane code:

```
public Timer tmr;

        public taskpane()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            tmr = new Timer() { Interval = 500 };
            tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
            tmr.Enabled = true;
            tmr.Stop();
        }


void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (iw == null)
                setVars();

            if (_tp.lv_AttachmentList.Items.Count > 0)
                _ctp.Visible = true;

            tmr.Stop();
        }
```

setvars() is a command to pull in the proper iw and set the references to _tp and _ctp

Answer (score 3):

As far as the resize, just monitor your task pane's resize event and reset the size. However you might consider +why+ you'd want to do that. If there's a minimum necessary size for your taskpane, it might make more sense to restrict the minimum. and if the contents are resizable, maybe they should be.

You might also override the OnLayout method. That will often work better.

For the Close button, I think you'd want to intercept the "VisibleChanged" event and make the pane visible if it's been hidden. As I recall, taskpanes are not actually "closed" per se, but just set invisible.

Comment: I'm working on this right now, and you can't change the value of Visible while intercepting the event.  This may be something to put a timer on.

Comment: @drventure thanks for your answer! this is really more viable than mine! indeed my solution is more personal!

Answer (score 0):

I find a Solution for this One :

```
void NormalizeSize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.taskPane.Height > 558 || this.taskPane.Width > 718)
        {
            this.taskPane.Height = 558;
            this.taskPane.Width = 718;
        }
        else{
            this.taskPane.Width = 718;
            this.taskPane.Height = 558;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is okay if you are under orders to ship right-now. However, this is not a viable long-term solution. Hacks like this can lead to maintenance nightmares (other developers would not expect the solution to be this and its not very intuitive) and code-brittleness (minor changes can have rippling effects.)

Comment: Have to agree with phil here, those magic numbers scare me. Why 718 and 558? If the pane size is based somehow on it's contents, you'd be better off referencing the contents directly, ie basing the width and hieght of the taskpane on the bottom right position of one of the controls on it.

Comment: If I could I would unmark this as a SO answer. The answer from @drventure regarding resize events is much better, even the comment from Mathias with docking are both orthadox coding solutions. In ten years I expect to see the full version on DailyWTF

Comment: @thompson Okay seems to be more a personal Hack than a solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the "Must not be closed"-Part of the problem you can maybe use this one instead of a timer:

```
private void myCustomTaskPane_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!myCustomTaskPane.Visible)
  {
    //Start new thread to make the CTP visible again since changing the
    //visibility directly in this event handler is prohibited by Excel.
    new Thread(() =>
    {
      myCustomTaskPane.Visible = true;
    }).Start();
  }
}
```

Hope it helps,
Jörg